# GIT Branch Clarification

Tags: git, github

I have a few files in the master branch which have been committed.

Then I create another branch and switch to that branch as well.

Now in that another branch I modify the files which are also present in the master branch.

But still I have not committed the changes on the other branch.

If I try to switch to the master branch it lets me to switch carrying all changes I have made on the other branch.

GIT should not allow me to switch to master branch until I commit the changes in the other branch right?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Git will let you switch accross branches, even if you have uncommited changes. However, it will NOT let you switch to another branch if doing so would result in a conflict.

Comment: As i have mentioned above I have modifed all files and they do cause conflicts.Even then I'm able to switch without committing.

Comment: Can you give an example where I can simulate that conflict and check if its working fine

Comment: No, it's not a conflict.  At the moment, both branch & master point to the same commit.  Your changes on branch are just a changeset to files that exist in that commit.   You're just switching whether to apply that changeset to branch or to master - no conflict at all.